# how to match the character start with and end with in awk

Tags: bash, awk

I am using awk. I have several names like

```
rs123123789_G    rs9888_A     rs23789_GA rs23789_GASDFAS
```

I want to find the name start with rs and end with single character in awk (rs123123789_G, rs9888_A).
I tried use

```
~/^rs[0-9]+[A-Z]$/
```

But it does not work.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You're missing the underscore :

```
~/^rs[0-9]+_[A-Z]$/
```

All the 3 names in your example are starting with `rs` and all are ending with a single alphabetic character - `G`, `A`, `S` respectively. Your requirement is that they should end with single alphabetic character *after* `_`.